# Emacs compilation buffer display hex value for quotation mark

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs, compilation

I m new to emacs , and using it for c programming.But on compiling in emacs, compilation buffer display message that contain hex value instead of quotation mark as show in image.

[image]

But on compile in terminal it display message as,

[image]

Search on Google but didn't get any things, is there any setting that i missed.

How to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the environment variable LC_ALL for the compiling command, i.e. configure it to something like

```
LC_ALL=C make
```

Comment: Solved just need to change Language Environment as shown in [Here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Language-Environments.html)

Comment: @Rohit: Note that it changes the environment globally for all the buffers. My reply only affects the compilation buffer.